# getting fadeIn is not a function although I did add jQuery to my HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut method.
This is what I have so far:

```
var fadeMainGrid = function() { 
$("#picturesGrid").fadeIn();
};
```

This is how I added jQuery to my HTML file:

```
<body dir="rtl">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


...
...

</body>
```

but still, when I try to run fadeMainGrid function, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeIn is not a function
```

Can't understand what this is happening, I never wrote JS nor used jQuery till this project. Searching the web yield nothing, as everything gave me the same error. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're loading the *slim* bundle, which according to [the downloads page](https://jquery.com/download/#jquery):

> ...excludes the ajax and effects modules.

`fadeIn` and `fadeOut` would fall into that category. You may need to replace your jQuery bundle with one containing more capabilities.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that as I was getting jQuery through the Bootstrap website.